# GRPC core: Stream removed error server stream, when server takes more then 30 seconds

Tags: c#, stream, grpc

**Update 08-06-2023**
The issue is fixed. The problem was caused by threat prevention from our Firewall software. At first we could not see any drops on the firewall. For this to become visible debug logging had to be enabled.

---

A stream removed error occurs in the following specific scenario:

- GRPC server stream where the server takes more than 60 seconds before returning to the client
- Using Grpc.Core.Channel(Grpc.Net.Client.GrpcChannel does not cause this)
- Running and calling the server in Azure over a public IP does **not** cause this issue.
- Running and calling the server in Azure using a private IP over an internal network hub **does** cause the issue.

Questions:

- What might be the possible cause of this issue?
- How come Grpc.Net.Client.GrpcChannel doesn't generate this error, while the Grpc.Core.Channel does?
- What might be a configuration on the network hub that could cause the issue?

Exception message:

Status(StatusCode="Unknown", Detail="Stream removed", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1668425723.993000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:<IP>:5000","file":"......\src\core\lib\surface\call.cc","file_line":953,"grpc_message":"Stream removed","grpc_status":2}")

Wireshark capture:
[image]

Proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "GrpcDemoServer";

package greet;

service Greeter {
  rpc SayHelloStream (HelloRequest) returns (stream StreamHelloReply);
}

message HelloRequest {  
  string name = 1;
  int32 sleepTime =2;
}

message StreamHelloReply {
    string message = 1;
}
```

Server code:

```
public override async Task SayHelloStream(HelloRequest request, IServerStreamWriter<StreamHelloReply> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(request.SleepTime);//70 seconds
                await responseStream.WriteAsync(new StreamHelloReply
                {
                    Message = $"Hello {i}"
                });
            }
        }
```

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
                    {
                        // Setup a HTTP/2 endpoint without TLS.
                        options.ListenAnyIP(5000, o => o.Protocols =
                            HttpProtocols.Http2);

                    });
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
       
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddGrpc();
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_CONNECTIONSTRING"]);
        }
       
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseRouting();
                        
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            { 
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();
                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

Client code:

```
var channel = new Channel("<IP ADDRESS>", 1234, ChannelCredentials.Insecure, new[]
                {
                    new ChannelOption( "grpc.keepalive_time_ms", 1000 ),
                    new ChannelOption( "grpc.http2.max_pings_without_data", 0 ),
                    new ChannelOption( "grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls", 1 )
                });

                var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
                using var transfer = client.SayHelloStream(GetRequest("Test", 70));
                while (await transfer.ResponseStream.MoveNext(CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    var response = transfer.ResponseStream.Current;
                    client.SayHello(GetRequest(response.Message, 1));
                    Console.WriteLine(response.Message);
                }
```

I tried using the following ChannelOptions to prevent this, but without success:

grpc.keepalive_time_ms => 1000

grpc.http2.max_pings_without_data => 0

grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls => 1

---

**Update 08-05-2023** 
For a full overview of updates see: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/31640

Originally we thought the timeout was at 60 seconds, but it is a bit more complicated(it seems to be at 30 seconds).

| Time between messages | Fails after message |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 5 |
| 1 | 28 |
| 40 | 2 |
| 61 | 2 |

Also I got the stream working **SOMETIMES** in a very specific scenario:

- The server is running as a GRPC core Server in a console window with GRPC_TRACE set to TCP and GRPC_VERBOSITY set to DEBUG
- The client is running in a console window with GRPC_TRACE set to TCP and GRPC_VERBOSITY set to DEBUG
- Once one message is successful after the breaking point of about 30 seconds all subsequent message will also be successful.

So it seems that somehow giving the client/server more time during the processing of the TCP message can influence if it fails or succeeds.

How come that when logging is enabled sometimes the connection does not get reset?